# Apache Jackrabbit: RepositoryException: This session has been closed

Tags: java, exception, jackrabbit

I am working with Apache Jackrabbit.

I found an exception, I tried a lot but didn't get the reason behind this exception.

Please help me in solving this.

**Exception :-**

```
javax.jcr.RepositoryException: This session has been closed.
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.jcr2spi.SessionImpl.checkIsAlive(SessionImpl.java:922)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.jcr2spi.ItemImpl.checkStatus(ItemImpl.java:436)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.jcr2spi.NodeImpl.getProperties(NodeImpl.java:489)
    at edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.frontier.DocIDServer.getDocId(DocIDServer.java:112)
    at edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.WebCrawler.processPage(WebCrawler.java:286)
    at edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.WebCrawler.run(WebCrawler.java:189)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

**Edit No. 1**

Code is as follows,

```
Repository repository = JcrUtils.getRepository("http://localhost:4502/crx/server");
Session session = repository.login(new SimpleCredentials("admin", "admin".toCharArray()));

// Obtain the query manager for the session via the workspace ...
QueryManager queryManager = session.getWorkspace().getQueryManager();

// Create a query object ...
String expression = "SELECT * FROM [sling:OrderedFolder] AS s WHERE ISDESCENDANTNODE([/docIDsDB])";
Query query = queryManager.createQuery(expression, javax.jcr.query.Query.JCR_SQL2);

// Execute the query and get the results ...
QueryResult result = query.execute();

// Iterate over the nodes in the results ...
NodeIterator nodeIter = result.getNodes();

session.logout();

while(nodeIter.hasNext()){
    Node node = nodeIter.nextNode();
    System.out.println(node.getProperty("url").getString());
    System.out.println(node.getProperty("docid").getString());

}
```

**Exception**

```
javax.jcr.RepositoryException: This session has been closed.
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.jcr2spi.SessionImpl.checkIsAlive(SessionImpl.java:922)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.jcr2spi.ItemImpl.checkStatus(ItemImpl.java:436)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.jcr2spi.NodeImpl.getProperty(NodeImpl.java:471)
    at jackrabbit.JackRabbit.main(JackRabbit.java:111)
```

**Line 111 is**

```
System.out.println(node.getProperty("url").getString());
```

In Jackrabbit, node and children are all of sling:orderedFolder type.

Comment: The stacktrace clearly points you to SessionImpl.java:922 where the state of session is closed... rectify that and you are good to go.

Comment: Post a Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (http://sscce.org/), please, to show us the source of the problem. Here you show only the consequence. With both we can imagine the cause.

Comment: @Aura Yes, it clearly shows that session is ended. I tried to reslove bu I didn't understand why this session closes.

Comment: I would think the `session.logout();` near line 107 would have something to do with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just keep the JCR Session open as long as you access the Nodes that it provides.

You should move your Session.logout() call to a finally clause that's after all the code that uses what the Session provides.

Comment: Actuallt I solved this problem. And I am going to answer this question. But you give the answer. Anyways thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

You should test `session.isLive()` before you reuse a stored `Session`, and re-acquire it if this method returns `false`.